# Get pure SQL from Drupal::entityQuery

Tags: 8, database

Given the following code, how can I print the SQL that is generated?

```
$bundle='my_bundle_type';
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('status', 1);
$query->condition('type', $bundle);
$entity_ids = $query->execute();
```

What I have tried:

- `__toString()` doesn't work
- `dpq($query)` throws an error

Answer (score 13):

With debug tag (**devel module is mandatory**) we can print the raw sql.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('foo')->condition('bar', 'xyz')->addTag('debug');
$ids = $query->execute();
```

Comment: This isnt working for me. I have Devel enabled.

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE**

My original answer is not valid anymore, now there's a good solution for this, see [Sukhjinder Singh answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/249967/2604). In short: use Devel module and add tag 'debug', execute it and query will be printed.

```
$entityQueryObject->addTag('debug')->execute();
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

As @kiamlaluno says, the problem is [\Drupal::entityQuery()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8.2.x) implements [QueryInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/interface/QueryInterface/8.2.x), not [SelectInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Database!Query!SelectInterface.php/interface/SelectInterface/8.2.x). dpq needs its first argument to implements that SelectInterface.

The object returned by \Drupal::entityQuery() is a [Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21Sql%21Query.php/class/Query/8.1.x). This object has a protected property that implements the SelectInterface:

```
  /**
   * The build sql select query.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Database\Query\SelectInterface
   */
  protected $sqlQuery;
```

Unfortunately, the Query objects don't allow to access the $sqlQuery or print the SQL string.

As a very **quick and dirty** hack you can edit the Query class file in *core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Query/Sql/Query.php*, change the $sqlQuery property to be public, and access it directly.

In Query.php, `protected $sqlQuery` should be `public $sqlQuery;`.

Then you can use the [dpq function from devel module](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpq/8.x-1.x) with the internal property. Make sure the [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module is installed (so it's enabled).

> Prints a SQL string from a DBTNG Select object. Includes quoted
>   arguments.

So in your case:

```
$sql_string = dpq($query->sqlQuery, TRUE));
```

Or just:

```
kint(dpq($query->sqlQuery, TRUE));
```

## dpq() Parameters

- **object $query**: An object that implements the SelectInterface interface.
- **boolean $return**: Whether to return the string. Default is FALSE, meaning to print it and return $query instead.
- **string $name**: Optional name for identifying the output.

## IMPORTANT!!

This is a dirty trick, you should revert the Query.php file when you are done. Hacking Drupal core is a very bad practice and kittens, ponies and other puppies are suffering when you do that. Maybe even some unicorns are - better think twice about it.

## Final thoughts

This a dirty workaround. Another better approach may exist but I'm not aware of it. If there is not a better way Drupal core may add some functionality to get the SQL string as sometimes is needed when debugging, and frankly, this hack is not a good way to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I stated in the question the dpq throws error, I think it doesn't work with \Drupal::entityQuery

Comment: The OP said that function throws an error. He didn't say which error, exactly, so it could be the Devel module has not been installed.

Comment: I didn't see it. As @kiamlaluno probably devel mdoule is not installed.

Comment: I think the problem is the first argument `dpq()` is expecting: The object returned from `\Drupal::entityQuery()` implements [`QueryInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/interface/QueryInterface/8.2.x), not `SelectInterface`. The first doesn't require the classes implementing it to have an `addExpression()` method, for example.

Comment: You are totally right @kiamlaluno, editing with a quick and dirty workaround.

Comment: @downvoter, please explain the down vote. If you know a proper way to get the SQL string please share with us, I'm very interested in do it without this multiple-times-said dirt and quick hack.

Comment: What a lovely trick.  Thanks for sharing. I don't call these things "hacks", but solutions ;) . I am upvoting the answer, because it does whatever I need to do in my case. However, there must be some better one-liner that does the job. That's why I am not yet marking the question as answered.

Comment: Tweaking core is always a hack, the API should allow this. Seems like the Query class itself needs a _toString() if it wants to keep $sqlQuery protected.

Comment: @Grayside Feel free to submit a patch to Drupal core.

Comment: The right issue is https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2902311

Answer (score 2):

With installed `Devel` module you can get the string with raw SQL query from EntityQuery class via:

```
$rawSqlQuery = (string) dpq($entityQuery);
echo $rawSqlQuery;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

[How can I debug entity queries in Drupal 8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/218011/how-can-i-debug-entity-queries-in-drupal-8)

See the question in this link.  This is a solution that has worked for me, if you add those two functions to a custom module, all you have to do is tag an entity query with "debug" to output the string version of the sql query.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the __toString() option as below and look at the SQL in the $query variable.

```
 $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
->condition('status', 1)
->condition('type', 'basic_page')
->condition('changed', $utc_start, '>=')
->__toString();
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it works, I am using Drupal 9.3. I just dumped like this : dump($query->__toString());

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReflectionClass in this case.

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass(get_class($query));
$property = $reflection->getProperty('sqlQuery');
$entity_ids = $query->execute(); // this is required
$sql = (string)$property->getValue($queryObject);
echo $sql;
```

Answer (score -2):

Enable  Devel and Devel Kint modules then  just try

```
 kint ($query);
```

Comment: This outputs the query object in a readable fashion, not the pure sql that would be generated by the query.

Comment: @oknate you can find raw query in kint output

Comment: Awesome, can you add instructions to your answer on how to do that?

Comment: I tried using kint, unfortunately this eats my memory on a simple query.

Comment: @OlegVidenov yes, it's good debugging tool but memory hungry.