# Show full query for anonymous user

Tags: views, 8

I'm currently troubleshooting an issue where anonymous users and certain roles see a different set of results from a view than administrators and roles with more permissions do. The view is supposed to have two node results, but for anonymous and others, there is only one.

I am trying to get the full SQL of the final query that's creating the anonymous pages. I'm using `hook_views_query_alter()`, and I can get the full query using `dpq($view->query->query());` when I'm logged in as an administrator.

However, when I'm an anonymous user, or one of the other roles encountering the bug, I get SQL like this: `((taxonomy_index.status = :db_condition_placeholder_7) AND (node_field_data.type IN (:db_condition_placeholder_8)))`.

I tried getting the placeholder values from [a technique I used in drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51333/how-to-print-the-query-which-is-built-using-db-select/51338), using the `arguments()` method, but apparently that doesn't exist in Drupal 8.

But moreover, I would like to avoid matching up the string `db_condition_placeholder` manually, because I could make a mistake, and misdiagnose what the source of the problem is. I want the full query string that drupal sends to the database, so that I can debug it directly with the MySQL server.

I tried other techniques listed [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231259/get-pure-sql-from-drupalentityquery), such as `->addTag('debug')`, which apparently did nothing, and `kint($view->query->query());`, which only returns output for administrator users.

How can I get the full query string from a view executed for anonymous users?

Comment: Maybe try turning off SQL Rewriting? I dislike that it's the default as I usually am using views to get around access restrictions anyway. You can still place  query based filtering to do _simple_ access anyway.

Comment: If `kint($view->query->query())` works, then take `$view->query->query()` and simply try to `echo` it (maybe with one of the methods listed in the output `kint($view->query->query())` gave you).

Comment: To display the query using kint($view->query->query()), go to the permission page for devel and enable kint for anon users.

Comment: @mradcliffe Disabling SQL rewriting worked. Could you please post that as an answer? I'd like to accept it : )

Comment: Sure, I didn't think it was exactly an answer to the specific question, but it probably makes sense to add it, @user1359. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: This does not answer the question of "trying to get the full SQL of the final query that's creating the anonymous pages", but answers the underlying issue.

**tl;dr Checking the Advanced Settings > Query > Disable SQL Rewriting option will allow views to return consistent results.**

#### Explanation

The views module (contrib and core) configures views with restrictive entity access enabled by default. This sends the query object through `hook_db_rewrite_sql` (6), `hook_query_TAG_alter` (7, 8). Nodes for instance will add in joins to the `node_access` table, which can be prohibitively expensive on queries.

**This is important** for sites that use complex entity access where one node may be hidden from view based on [node grants/access rights](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/group/node_access/8.6.x).

However query results will be different when querying entities (such as nodes) depending on if you are logged in. This can be frustrating when building a view as a site builder - what you see is not what you get.

It may not necessary to use SQL rewriting because a view has other access restrictions. **Checking the Advanced Settings > Query > Disable SQL Rewriting option will allow views to return consistent results.**

This is usually the first thing I do when creating a view unless I specifically need the extra access checks because

1. It improves performance significantly.
2. I create selective and filtered views that naturally restrict data using filters, contextual filters and view access restrictions.

#### Update 2019.06

Note that the views module changed the label for this setting from "Disable SQL Rewriting" to "Disable Access Checks".

Comment: The option `Disable SQL Rewriting` is unchecked by default. Did you mean to word that `Checking the Advanced Settings > Query > Disable SQL Rewriting option`?

Comment: Yes, thank you, @prkos.