# How can I display a block to public?

Tags: views

I created a view block and placed it in the content region. There is no role restriction. That means all users can view the block. However, only authenticated users can view the block. I am not sure how to fix it.

> [image: screenshot]

How can I display the block to public?

---

[image]

Comment: Doesn't sound anything to do with the block itselfs and more likely to do with your view. Check within your view there's permissions in therea and also anon users might not have permission to view the content your displaying within your view so that's worth checking too

Comment: I checked the views and it looked correct. Please see the update.

Comment: It will be cached, try clearing the caches

Comment: Do you have access restrictions on the content that view is returning? If that's the case, anonymous users will never see that content because by default SQL rewriting is enabled. You'd need to disable SQL rewriting in your view. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/270298/show-full-query-for-anonymous-user/270430#270430

Comment: Public did not have access to the content type as per requirement. Because of that, they cant see the view. I guess I need to change the requirement. Thanks!